# How to do async code synchronously Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a function that iterates over a file list and then for each file, it calls an async method which does some image manipulation and then pushes the image to an array.

The issue is that the async calls happen at the same time and so it locks up the UI. So I would like to iterate over the list but only call the function when the previous one is finished.

```
Array.from(files).forEach(data => {
    if (data.size > 5000000) {
        this.toastr_service.error('FILE ' + data.name + ' EXCEEDS FILE SIZE LIMIT (5MB)');
    }else {
        this.asyncFunc(data).subscribe(result => {
            this._photos.push(result);
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post your code and(/or) a [mcve] reproducing your issue

Comment: why not chain the requests?

Comment: Use RxJS - it handles async code really well

Comment: As @mast3rd3mon wisely suggested, you should probably chain the requests. Since your application doesn't seem to work synchronously, you should chain with fork join. EDIT: Also, don't forget. The subscribe method also has a "done" callback, in which you can apply logic that should only be executed when it SUCCESSFULLY completed the task.

Comment: @trichetriche I have added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `map` function of arrays as well as RxJS's `forkJoin`

```
forkJoin(Array
  .from(files)
  .map(file => file.size < 5000000 && this.asyncFunc(file) || undefined)
  .filter(value => !!value)
).subscribe(([...responses]) => {
  console.log(responses);
  this._photos.push(...responses);
});
```

`forkJoin` will make all calls where the file size is under 5Mb (`map` & `filter` take care of that), and once all the calls are made, the responses will be pushed into your array.

**EDIT** If you want your calls to be sequenced, use `concat` instead :

```
concat(...Array
  .from(files)
  .map(file => file.size < 5000000 && this.asyncFunc(file) || undefined)
  .filter(value => !!value)
).subscribe((...responses) => {
  this._photos.push(...responses);
  console.log(this.photos);
});
```

Comment: it seems to not be doing anything no console log appears and i am using the same files for the input as i used before

Comment: My bad, I inverted the condition ... It was looking for files sizing more than 5Mb !

Comment: @user3074140 I edited my answer, feel free to try it

Comment: I appreciate the help. I still dont seem to get a console.log The code I had was fine for one image but multiple would cause ui issues. Does this code run the async functions one after each other as that is what I am trying to achieve. I tried your updated code and the UI seemed to lock up in the same way.

Comment: HTTP calls are async. Your UI can't be blocked by that, or if it does, it's because of something else. [This working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brtbve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) shows it indeed works, if you are wondering.

Comment: I see the function I have does some image manipulation and returns an observable that I subscribe to to get the new image. but there is no way to call the asycfunc only when the previous has given the result in this iterative manner

Comment: Why would you wait for previous images to finish their HTTP call, if they aren't related to each other ? The fastest would be to make every HTTP call at once ...

Comment: ah they are not http calls. they are local functions created by someone else theres stuff to do with putting the image on a canvas and then manipulating it. I dont understand any of that.

Comment: Well anyway, forkjoin preserves the order of the Observables (which I mistakenly called HTTP calls), so every call should be made in the right order.

Comment: but does that mean the calls and results come in the right order but each call will run concurrently and not one after the other?

Comment: They will run all concurrently, not one after another. If you want to run them one after another, you have to use `concat`. I updated the stackblitz, you can take a look at it : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brtbve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts. Open your console and see how the messages are displayed at intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Test this solution ?

```
Array.from(files).flatMap(async data => {
  const result = await asyncFunc(data);
  this._photos.push(result);
});
```